# django rest framework nested routes

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I try to implement a REST API with DRF, and want to do the following:

1. /profile/ returns serialized representation of logged in user
2. /profile/keys/ returns some other info, also about logged in user
3. API root should look like this:

   - /profile/
   - /some-other-stuff/

where profile expands to

- /
- /keys/

Is there a way to expand /profile/ to the picture mentioned above *without* including /keys/ into response for /profile/ or at least to the following:

- /profile/
- /profile/keys/

Comment: https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers will solve your problem I guess.

Comment: @nik Probably not, since all routing goes through some sort of {pk} there. Or do I miss something? Could you be more specific?

Comment: yeah that's right, it expects the pk for nested url.

Comment: @nik in my case no pk is required - data is fetched in relation to authenticated user

Comment: I see, may be list_route help, but it will be workaround only.